# Android Room: Migration didn't properly handle, Expected and Found are equal

Tags: java, android, migration, android-room

The expected and found are literally equal. Why is the room complaining here?

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception while computing database live data.
        at androidx.room.RoomTrackingLiveData.refreshRunnable$lambda-0(RoomTrackingLiveData.kt:74)
        at androidx.room.RoomTrackingLiveData.lambda$UkyPj-RMUoTXOMbUuy5NWSwmo0E(Unknown Source:0)
        at androidx.room.-$$Lambda$RoomTrackingLiveData$UkyPj-RMUoTXOMbUuy5NWSwmo0E.run(Unknown Source:2)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:923)
     Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Migration didn't properly handle: emergency(hero.db.model.Emergency).
     Expected:
    TableInfo{name='emergency', columns={emergency_record_id=Column{name='emergency_record_id', type='INTEGER', affinity='3', notNull=notNull, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='null'}, vehicle_plate=Column{name='vehicle_plate', type='TEXT', affinity='2', notNull=notNull, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='null'}, device_id=Column{name='device_id', type='TEXT', affinity='2', notNull=notNull, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='null'}, user_id=Column{name='user_id', type='INTEGER', affinity='3', notNull=notNull, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='null'}, sent_to_cloud=Column{name='sent_to_cloud', type='INTEGER', affinity='3', notNull=notNull, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='null'}, location=Column{name='location', type='TEXT', affinity='2', notNull=notNull, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='null'}, id=Column{name='id', type='INTEGER', affinity='3', notNull=notNull, primaryKeyPosition=1, defaultValue='null'}, emergency_description=Column{name='emergency_description', type='TEXT', affinity='2', notNull=notNull, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='null'}, timestamp=Column{name='timestamp', type='INTEGER', affinity='3', notNull=notNull, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='null'}}, foreignKeys=[], indices=[]}
     Found:
    TableInfo{name='emergency', columns={emergency_record_id=Column{name='emergency_record_id', type='INTEGER', affinity='3', notNull=notNull, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='null'}, vehicle_plate=Column{name='vehicle_plate', type='TEXT', affinity='2', notNull=notNull, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='null'}, device_id=Column{name='device_id', type='TEXT', affinity='2', notNull=notNull, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='null'}, user_id=Column{name='user_id', type='INTEGER', affinity='3', notNull=notNull, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='null'}, sent_to_cloud=Column{name='sent_to_cloud', type='INTEGER', affinity='3', notNull=notNull, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='null'}, location=Column{name='location', type='TEXT', affinity='2', notNull=notNull, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='null'}, id=Column{name='id', type='INTEGER', affinity='3', notNull=notNull, primaryKeyPosition=1, defaultValue='null'}, emergency_description=Column{name='emergency_description', type='TEXT', affinity='2', notNull=notNull, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='null'}, timestamp=Column{name='timestamp', type='INTEGER', affinity='3', notNull=notNull, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='null'}}, foreignKeys=[], indices=[]}
```

This is my entity:

```
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Builder
@Entity(tableName = AppDatabase.TABLE_EMERGENCY)
public class Emergency {

    @ColumnInfo(name = "emergency_record_id")
    private Integer emergencyRecordId;

    @ColumnInfo(name = "vehicle_plate")
    private String vehiclePlate;

    @ColumnInfo(name = "device_id")
    private String deviceId;

    @ColumnInfo(name = "user_id")
    private Long userId;

    @ColumnInfo(name = "sent_to_cloud")
    @JsonIgnore
    private Boolean sentToCloud = false;

    @ColumnInfo(name = "location")
    private LocationRoute location;

    @PrimaryKey
    @ColumnInfo(name = "id")
    private Long id;

    @ColumnInfo(name = "emergency_description")
    private String emergencyDescription;

    @ColumnInfo(name = "timestamp")
    private Date timeStamp;
}
```

this is my migration:

```
 "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + TABLE_EMERGENCY + " (\n " +
                            "emergency_record_id    INTEGER                               ,\n " +
                            "vehicle_plate          TEXT                                  ,\n " +
                            "device_id              TEXT                                  ,\n " +
                            "user_id                INTEGER                               ,\n " +
                            "sent_to_cloud          INTEGER                               ,\n " +
                            "location               TEXT                                  ,\n " +
                            "id                     INTEGER     PRIMARY KEY       NOT NULL,\n " +
                            "emergency_description  TEXT                                  ,\n " +
                            "timestamp              INTEGER                               \n " +
                            " );"
```

Answer (score 0):

Rather than attempting to ascertain the issue with your create SQL *(not that it is incorrect, but that it doesn't meet Room's expectations)*. I would suggest using the SQL that is **generated by Room**, it will be correct.

After adding the **Emergency** class as one of the entities in the `@Database` annotation of the **AppDatabase** class, **compile the project** (CTRL+F9).

- Obviously you would have done this. Mentioned as a step to undertake when adding a migration from the start.

Then in the **Android View**, find the **java(generated)**, expand each and look for **AppDatabase_Impl** e.g. :-

[image]

Within this locate the **createAllTables** (generally at the top) and find the respective _db.execSQL for the table(s) e.g. :-

[image]

and use that for the SQL in the Migration e.g. :-

```
static Migration m1to2 = new Migration(1,2) {
    @Override
    public void migrate(@NonNull SupportSQLiteDatabase database) {
        /*
        database.execSQL(
        "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + TABLE_EMERGENCY + " (" +
                "emergency_record_id INTEGER," +
                "vehicle_plate TEXT," +
                "device_id TEXT," +
                "user_id INTEGER, " +
                "sent_to_cloud INTEGER, " +
                "location TEXT," +
                "id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL," +
                "emergency_description TEXT," +
                "timestamp INTEGER" +
                ");"
        );

         */
        database.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `emergency` (`emergency_record_id` INTEGER, `vehicle_plate` TEXT, `device_id` TEXT, `user_id` INTEGER, `sent_to_cloud` INTEGER, `location` INTEGER, `id` INTEGER, `emergency_description` TEXT, `timestamp` INTEGER, PRIMARY KEY(`id`))");
    }
};
```

> why is room complaining here?

Here's some pointers, but as originally stated, is it worth delving into this.

- Your code that fails commented out (after removing line feeds), as that was tested:-
- I believe that you will find that the migration doesn't then fail and of course there is no need to spend time comparing the **expected** and **found** (I couldn't see anything that was obvious).

  - you may notice a difference in that Room encloses table and column names in **``**'s, this protects against a clash with an SQLite keyword (not that I can see any location and timestamp, the most likely candidates, are not [keywords](https://www.sqlite.com/lang_keywords.html))
  - The other noticeable difference is that the **id** column is INTEGER (without NOT NULL) (pretty sure that PRIMARY KEY coded as part of the column or table definition is fine).
  - If you wish to determine the exact issue you could run tests progressively changing from one to the other.

As you can probably see, I have run through using what code you have available but with some changes to cater for other code (such as LocationRoute class) and also the removal of some of the annotations.

Comment: thats awesome man, thanks a lot. i ended up fixing the problem by switching to automigrations in that case. but this tip will be awesome for the future

Comment: Hi Mike. I updated this answer because the redundant phrase is no longer in the OP's question. I suppose your reply can be taken as implicitly the "please help" that the OP is after 